# Webcryto getRandomValues() implementation in popular browsers

Tags: google-chrome, safari, random-seed, webcrypto-api

Where can I find the implementation details of `getRandomValues()` from webcrypto for popular browers? i.e. Chrome, Safari, Edge.

According to the W3C specs of WebCrypto, there's no lower bound on the entropy from getRandomValues().

I want to find out how secure each implementation from the major browsers are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to understand each browsers implementation of WebCrypto is to look at the source where possible.

Generally (certainly with IE/Edge and Safari) they try to use platform capabilities where present when dealing with randomness.

To understand the kinds of things platforms see https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/419.pdf. This is fairly representative approach.

I believe in the case of Chrome they rely on BoringSSL for this and Firefox uses NSS.